How would you analyze or explain this philosophical sentence?
I am reading a book with my friends. We all are not native speakers. We have different opinions on the following sentence about how to read it. I hope you could show us the grammatical structure of it.
The sentence in question:

Our attention is directed to kinds of names corresponding to kinds of things named, with primitive names (i.e. letters) corresponding to elements, more complex linguistic forms corresponding to elemental compounds.

My understanding:
Our attention is directed to [kinds of names corresponding to kinds of things named, with primitive names (i.e. letters) corresponding to elements], [more complex linguistic forms corresponding to elemental compounds].
So basically, I understand 'kinds of names with primitive names' as what 'our attention' directed to and as an apposition to it(kinds of names) 'more complex linguistic forms'.
So I understand "with" as denoting having-relation as in a sentence like "a girl with red hair". Is that possible?
Some contexts for your understanding:

According to my understanding, names like "Socrates" corresponding to real Socrates, and "Socrates" has primitive names such as "s", "o", "c", "r", and so on. These primitive names correspond again to phonemes which are elements (stocheion; in its original sense). And this analogy suggests that a thing named (Socrates) has its elemental structure as the name ("Socrates") has its elemental structure ("s", "o" ...) in it.

This is a very technical text on Plato's philosophy of language. However, what is at stake is not a content, but the structure which any well educated native speaker can hopefully see.

'primitive names' here means letters such as 'a', 'b', 'c'.... So it is not likely that these primitive names are complex linguistic forms.



I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://philosophy.stackexchange.com

There's one main clause stating the concept being described:

Our attention is directed to kinds of names corresponding to kinds of things named

The rest of the sentence after "with" clarifies this using an analogy between names and chemical elements and compounds.
It could be rewritten as:

Our attention is directed to kinds of names corresponding to kinds of things named. For example, primitive names (i.e. letters) correspond to elements, while more complex linguistic forms correspond to elemental compounds.


Thank you for your fast answer. But could you give me the synthetic analysis of "with"?

Our attention is directed to kinds of names corresponding to kinds of things named, and primitive names correspond to elements. Is that what you meant?

X with Y means that Y is related to X in some way. In this case Y is a set of examples that clarifies X.


Our attention is directed to kinds of names corresponding to kinds of things  named, with primitive names (i.e. letters) corresponding to elements, more complex linguistic forms corresponding to elemental compounds.

This sentence has for aim to explain that the writer and some group of persons with the same interest are considering the connection between nomenclature and what it names, and that the basic fact concerning this question is that letters are used for elemental things, while more complex linguistic forms are used for elemental compounds.
"With" being used to show that one fact (examination of nomenclature and names) is considered in relation to another (letters are used for elements and more complex forms for compounds).

(OLD) ​ with 8 used when considering one fact in relation to another

She won't be able to help us with all the family commitments she has.
It's much easier compared with last time.


A rewriting could be as follows.

Our attention is directed to what  kinds of names correspond to what kinds of things named; while/whereas  primitive names (i.e. letters) correspond to elements, more complex linguistic forms correspond to elemental compounds.

Addition prompted by comment (From you and Barmar's answer I have noticed that I should give you some other background understanding. So I edited my original question. Please have a look again and help me with more information I gave about the text.)
The interpretation of "with" to match that of "with" in "girl with red hair" is not correct ; the meaning of "with" in that context is "having or carrying". What is to be had or carried would be an assertion  (X is used for Y and Z for W), and that makes no sense. Moreover, no entity as made sufficiently clear from the OP's sentence could be said to "have" that.

Thank you for your answer. From you and Barmar's answer I have noticed that I should give you some other background understanding. So I edited my original question. Please have a look again and help me with more information I gave about the text. Sorry for the confusion!

Thanks! Well, like I wrote in number 1, any name (e. g. Socrates) has alphabet (S, o, c, r, a ..). The primitive names are here alphabet letters.
